# backuppc has missing menu items after installation

Tags: 14.04, apache2, backuppc

Problem: backuppc is missing essential menu items in its web interface.
Items "Edit Hosts", "Edit Config" etc are missing.

`backuppc` is installed on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.
I have even completely removed the `backuppc` application (using `dpkg --purge backupppc`), and re-installed it (apt-get install backuppc). Menu items are still missing.

[image: link-to-screenshot]

When running /usr/lib/backuppc/cgi-bin/index.cgi directly in the CLI, I do get the missing menu items. The HTML output from index.cgi includes:

```
<a href="?action=editConfig">Edit Config</a>
<a href="?action=editConfig&amp;newMenu=hosts">Edit Hosts</a>
```

I tried running de index.cgi on command line as root, backuppc and www-data, all having the same output. (I had to enable a login shell for www-data)

However, that is missing when accessing the `backuppc` admin from the console in the browser.

The file /etc/backuppc/config.pl contains:

```
$Conf{CgiAdminUserGroup} = 'backuppc';
$Conf{CgiAdminUsers}     = 'backuppc';
```

When I change `$Conf{CgiAdminUsers}` to `'*'` instead of `'backuppc'`, it works, but I prefer not to give admin access to all users, so this can only serve as a temporarily workaround.

apache configuration is default by installing backuppc package:

```
<Directory /usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin/>
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all

        Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        DirectoryIndex index.cgi

        AuthUserFile /etc/backuppc/htpasswd
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "BackupPC admin"
        require valid-user
</Directory>
```

The contents above are in `/etc/backuppc/apache.conf` which is symbolically linked from `/etc/apache2/conf.d/backuppc.conf`.

For problem analysis, I have added the following script to `/usr/lib/backuppc/cgi-bin/debug.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
printf("My userid is $> (%s)\n", (getpwuid($>))[0]);
```

The output, written in the apache `error.log`, after authentication, was:

```
My userid is 33 (www-data)
```

So the userid is incorrectly passed to BackupPc. The user id passed is `www-data` where I expected that the authenticated user id, passed to BackupPc would be `backuppc` as the latter is the one I used to login with. So probably, this is an apache configuration issue.

I have added a second cgi script `printenv.cgi` which output the environment variables. The script contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
foreach $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    $val = $ENV{$var};
    $val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;
    $val =~ s|"|\\"|g;
    print "${var}=\"${val}\"\n";
}
```

The output contained:

```
REMOTE_USER="$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER="
```

where backuppc requires that this environment variable `REMOTE_USER` contains the authenticated user (`backuppc` in my example). Turns out that an incorrect `REMOTE_USER` is the cause of the problem.

The diagnostic scripts were placed in `/usr/lib/backuppc/cgi-bin/` and were symbolically linked from `/usr/share/backuppc/cgi-bin/`. Their ownership was `backupc:www-data` and they were granted chmod `a+x` and `u+s` permissions.

Comment: A screenshot clearly indicating the problem would have been nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the output of `REMOTE_USER="$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER="`, I did a grep on `REMOTE_USER` in the configuration scripts below `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`. I found a `.conf` file that contained:

```
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
```

The `.conf` script was unrelated to backuppc.
Prefixing the REMOTE_USER line with `#`, and then restarting the services

```
# apachtectl restart
# service backuppc restart
```

resolved the issue.